# How to remove CSS "Font padding" in input fields with line-height?

Tags: html, css

I created a simple input field:

```html
<style>
    input {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
<input type="text" placeholder="Test">
```

[image: prview]

I would like to remove the "font padding" (which I marked orange). I tried to manipulate it with line-height but in my case I was only able to increase the "font padding" with it not decrease it. Does anyone have a solution how to decrease it?

The input field should look like this:
[image: preview 2]

Comment: try to input this text `ÂÊjpq_` and you will understand why that space is needed

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I know this. However in my case this input field only allows text so I doesn't really matter. This case won't cause. :)

Comment: but ÂÊjpq_ IS text, and j, p, q are basic lower case letters...

Comment: True sorry my field is very special. Only abc-ABC :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by fixing an input height. But that will work only when you don't have letters that are jumping out of the baseline (j, y, g...). If one of these letters appears, you will need to adjust/increase the height of the input with Javascript.

**Please note: I would not do that, but this is the solution for your question :D. Also, you will need Javascript code**

```css
input{
  font-size: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Test">
<input type="text" placeholder="Tesyt">
```

Comment: Thank you! I was exactly looking for this :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to wrap your input inside an inline-flex label . align-items and overflow then can help:

possible example:

```css
label input {
  font-size: 1em;
  border: none;
  background: none; 
  color: green;
}

label {
  height: 0.72em;
  display: inline-flex;
  border: inset 1px #555;
}

label,
input {
  font-size: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<label><input value="Test clipped 123456"></label> <input value="Test aside">
```

Comment: Hello @G-Cyrillus. Your answer is awesome. I also answered this question but your code is precise. I am definately rating it :) If you have time do have a look at my answer and suggest improvement. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a try and just come up with the following trick **using pure CSS** :
This does need some tweeks as per requirement.

```css
body{
  position:relative;
}
input{
  border:none;
  position:absolute;
  outline:none;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:29px;
  width:200px;
  background:none;
  z-index:3;
}

label{
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 9px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <label for="mytext"></label>
  <input type="text" id="mytext" value="WE ARE HERE">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hello, visual looks fine to me, maybe a top:-0.1em or so to offset a bit the imput from top would do. label could be in position:relative instead absolute to remain in the flow. input could also be a direct child of label, so no worries on focusing the input ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply and fruitful advises :)